# Sifrei Mussar/Machshava/Avodah from the Rishonim

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, mussar-ethics, rishonim

I'm looking for a list of some of the Seforim written by Rishonim that are in the category of either Mussar, Machshava, or Avodah (or anything else that fit into these categories.) For this question please leave out philosophical works (ones that are "entirely" philosophical in nature. If however they contain in it philosophical ideas but still fit into the above mentioned categories that would also be okay.)

Two examples that came to mind, [Sharei Teshuva](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yonah_Gerondi) and Chovos HaLavavos. However I'm sure there are many more and therefore whatever partial or complete list could be given as an answer to this would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "or anything else that fit into these categories"? Do you mean anything else (i.e. things not by _rishonim_) that fit into the categories of _musar_, _machashava_, and _avoda_ (like _M'silas Y'sharim_)?

Comment: @msh210 I meant "sub-categories" or things that maybe speak about other subjects as well not just these. I'll try and update the question. I'm looking only from Rishonim.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following is from an old project of mine. It is in rough chronological order, so I cut it off by the 15th century, but some Acharonim still managed to squeeze in. :)

**Classic Mussar Seforim**

The following is a select list of major works of mussar:

**Mishlei (Proverbs) – Shelomo HaMelech (King Solomon).** The book of Mishlei is probably the first work devoted entirely to mussar. As such, it provides much of the material that is utilized in all later works of mussar. Because the book of Mishlei is a mussar work, all the commentaries on it are also effectively works of mussar as well. In addition to the standard Biblical commentaries, there are several commentaries written specifically on Mishlei. Many of these are studied as mussar works in their right. Among these are:

- **Pirush Rabbeinu Yonah – Rabbeinu Yonah of Gerona** (c.1180-1263)
- **Pirush HaGra – Rav Eliyahu of Vilna (the Vilna Gaon)** (1720-1797)

**Pirkei Avos – Talmud.** Probably the most widely studied tractate of the Talmud. In addition to all the standard commentaries on the Mishna (such as the Rambam, Bartenura, and Tosefos Yom Tov), Pirkei Avos has been the subject of innumerable special commentaries. Many of these are considered classics in their own right. Among these are:

- **Pirush Rabbeinu Yonah – Rabbeinu Yonah of Gerona** (c.1180-1263)
- **HaChasid Ya’avetz – Rav Yosef Ya’avetz** (d. 1507). Rav Yosef Yaavetz
  also wrote a commentary on book of Tehillim (Psalms), and several
  books on Jewish belief.
- **Nachalas Avos – Rav Don Yitzchak Abarbanel** (1437-1508)
- **Medrash Shmuel – Rav Shmuel di Uzeda** (1538-1602). One of the most
  comprehensive commentaries on Pirkei Avos, the Medrash Shmuel is both
  a collection of earlier commentaries and an original commentary. Rav
  Shmuel di Uzeda was a disciple of the Arizal and Rav Chaim Vital. He
  also wrote commentaries on Megillas Rus and Megillas Eicha.
- **Ruach Chaim – Rav Chaim of Volozhin** (1749-1821).

**Avos D’Rebbi Noson**, a Talmudic work which expands upon the themes of Pirkei Avos.

**Chovos HaLevovos – Rabbeinu Bachya ibn Paquda** (Early 11th Century). Arguably the most important mussar work of all time, the Chovos HaLevovos is divided into ten Shearim (“Gates”). In each section, Rabbeinu Bachya precisely defines each concept and the principles related to it. These ten sections are:

1. **Shaar HaYichud (“Gate of Unity”)** – a philosophical discourse on the importance of proving to oneself that God exists, and the proper means by which to achieve this.
2. **Shaar HaBechina (“Gate of Discernment”)** – on perceiving God’s wisdom and control in the world around us.
3. **Shaar Avodas HaElokim (“Gate of the Service of God”)** – on our obligation to serve God.
4. **Shaar HaBitachon (“Gate of Trust”)** – on our obligation to trust God.
5. **Shaar Yichud HaMaaseh (“Gate of Unity of Action”)** – on the principle of devoting all one’s actions only to the service of God, and how to achieve this.
6. **Shaar HaKeniah (“Gate of Humility”)** – on the principle of humility.
7. **Shaar HaTeshuva (“Gate of Repentance”)** – on repentance.
8. **Shaar Cheshbon HaNefesh (“Gate of Self-Accounting”)** – on the importance of introspection and self-examination and the proper ways to do this.
9. **Shaar HaPrishus (“Gate of Abstinence”)** – on the value of separating oneself from physical and worldly pleasures, and the proper way to do so.
10. **Shaar Ahavas HaShem (“Gate of Love of God”)** – on loving God.

**Sefer HaYashar – Ascribed to Rabbeinu Tam – Rav Yaakov ben Meir** (1100-1171). A philosophical mussar work.

**Sefer Chasidim – Rabbeinu Yehuda HaChasid** (c.1150-1217). A very influential mussar work with substantial kabalistic input.

**Shaarei Teshuva – Rabbeinu Yonah of Gerona** (c.1180-1263). One of the most important and influential mussar works, the Shaarei Teshuva is considered the basic work on teshuva (repentance).

**Igeres HaRamban – Rav Moshe ben Nachman (Ramban)** (1195-1270). An extremely brief letter – only two or three pages long – the Igeres HaRamban was written by the Ramban to his son. Despite its brevity, this letter is considered a major mussar classic.

**Orchos Tzadikkim – Anonymous** (c.13th Century). An extremely popular work, the Orchos Tzadikkim is divided into twenty-eight Shearim.

**Orchos Chaim L’Ha’Rosh - Rabbeinu Asher ben Yechiel (Rosh)** (c.1250-1327). A very brief work consisting of admonishments to proper behavior and observance. Traditionally divided into seven sections for daily study.

**Maalos HaMiddos – Rabbeinu Yechiel** (13th Century) – A classic work of mussar that discusses in depth twenty-four middos and their opposites:

• Knowing God

• Loving God & One’s Fellow

• Fear of God & Parents

• Torah Study & the Fulfilment of the Mitzvos

• Kindness

• Charity

• Prayer

• Humility vs. Pride

• Modesty vs. Immorality

• Shame vs. Arrogance

• Faithfulness vs. Theft

• Honesty vs. Deceitfulness

• Compassion vs. Cruelty

• Amicability vs. Anger

• “A Good Name”

• Yetzer Tov vs. Yetzer Hara

• Teshuva (Repentance)

• Wisdom vs. Foolishness

• Wealth

• Diligence vs. Laziness

• Easily Satisfied vs. Gluttony

• Generosity vs. Stinginess

• Derech Eretz

• Peace vs. Contention & Gossip

**Menoras HaMe’or – Rav Yitzchak Aboav** (c.14th Century). An extremely popular work, the Menoras HaMe’or was translated into numerous languages including Spanish/Ladino, Yiddish, German, and, most recently, English. Much of the Menoras HaMe’or is made up of extensive selections from the Talmud and Midrashim with commentary by the author.

Comment: Best answer yet! Thank you! I'm choosing this as the correct answer. If you ever have any updates or additions please still add.

Comment: @Yehoshua Sure thing!

Comment: BTW, this is exactly the answer I was looking for. Not simply one recommendation of a Sefer per post.

Comment: What about Bet Elohim (HaMabit)? Kad HaKemach (Rabenu Bahyha)?

Comment: The Mabit is after the 15th century cut-off date I used for this post. Plus, I think the Beis Elokim is more of a hashkafa/philosophy book than a mussar sefer, so, in the larger document from which the material in this post was taken, I have it in the section of philosophical works. Kad HaKemach probably should be included (though it could also be considered more haskafic than mussar). However, the OP's request was broader than just mussar anyways. When I have time I will add it.

Comment: How is Medrash [sic] Shmuel a Rishon? Avos Dr' Nassan is Geonic. Orchos Chaim was not authored by Rosh.

Comment: @mevaqesh As I pointed out at the beginning of the answer, this is an excerpt from a larger piece of work of mine, and there are indeed some acharonim in the list.
I would be interested in learning your basis for saying that Orchos Chaim L'HaRosh was not written by the Rosh.

Comment: @LazerA קובץ בית אהרן וישראל שנה י"ב גליון ב' (סח) אורחות חיים המיוחס להרא"ש ואינו להרא"ש, עכ"ל: the Avos Dr' Nassan thing would also be improved if clarified לענ"ד.

Comment: @mevaqesh Unfortunately, that particular volume is not fully available at Hebrewbooks.org. However, the TOC does not mention any article on the topic. I am aware that there are those who have questioned the attribution of this sefer to the Rosh, but the mere fact that such questions have been raised is hardly basis for making a factual assertion that the sefer is not from the Rosh, especially given that this attribution has been made by many, many major figures including the Tosafos Yom Tov, the Shaagas Aryeh, the Seder HaDoros, the Chida, and, in modern times, R' Chaim Kanievsky.

Comment: @LazerA I concede, I did not have particular information that made the identification with the Rosh. I just thought that the modern consensus, as expressed in the quote is the attribution was mistaken. I was aware of the TYT and IIRC the Chida, but IIRC the TYT provides no proof; just says that that is the traditional identification. Given that the Chida's methods may have been great for his day, but do not stand up to the standards of modern scholarship, I simply assumed him to be have been factually misled.

Comment: @mevaqesh This does not appear to be a matter of academic debate. Encyclopedia Judaica, Otzar Yisroel, and others repeat the standard attribution to the Rosh. It seems that those who challenge this base themselves on some apparent conflicts between statements in OC and the Rosh's other seforim, and in that regard the methodology of the Chida was certainly more than sufficient. The TYT's opinion is particularly significant in that he was a major authority on the Rosh. The אורחות חיים להרא"ש המבואר has an appendix that addresses possible contradictions.

Answer (score 4):

You can try Orchot Chayim ([link](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/mahshevt/mekorot/orhot-2.htm)) written by [Rosh](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asher_ben_Jehiel).

Comment: That might as well have been added to my list of examples since I really couldn't think of anything else (which is exactly why I was asking. This did come to mind as well just couldn't remember the name of the Sefer itself.)

Comment: @Yehoshua Isn't something that could've been added to your examples an ideal answer? It makes it a perfect match for what you sought.

Comment: There's also [*"Sefer Hamaspik L'Ovdei Hashem"*](http://hebrewbooks.org/21288) by R' Avraham ben HaRambam. (Didn't want to edit your answer, but feel free to add it in or make a CW or something.)

Comment: Oh, and some of the Ramban's writings may fit the bill, particularly *Shaar HaGmul* and *Iggeres HaMussar*.

Answer (score 4):

**Sefer Chasidim**, by Rabbi Yehudah HaChasid.

Answer (score 3):

You might include the commentary of Rabeinu Yona to Pirkei Avos.

Answer (score 1):

This list from [Hebrew Wiki](http://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%92%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%94%3a%D7%A1%D7%A4%D7%A8%D7%99_%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%A8) includes many choices.

Comment: Link needs to be fixed (it seems...)

Comment: @Yehoshua fixed

Comment: Thanks. I could not figure out how to do it.

Comment: Not exactly the type of list I'm looking for